# Java: How can I get a JOption error to display when a non int or double is entered?

Tags: java, joptionpane

How can I get a JOption to display an error message when the user enters information that is not an int or a double, or when they enter nothing, and press ok? I had tried a while loop, but it just kept displaying the error message over and over, and the current code I have for it without any loops means that when the user actually enters a correct number into the box, the JOption error box appears anyway, but then when prompted to enter a value again, takes me to the next step. How can I 1. stop this first display from happening, and 2. actually get it to display and loop when they enter a null value, and 3. what sort of code I can put in for a non-number?

I thought that I had done it correct with the String entry, as seen below it, but I sometimes get a console error message with that. Any ideas on how to fix that too?

the int/double JOption:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid entry!", "Error!", 
JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    balance = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 
initial balance:", "Enter balance", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
```

for the string:

```
// if the dialog box is empty
    if (name.isEmpty()) {
        do {
            // display an error message
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name cannot be empty", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter customer name:", "Customers Name", // shows input box again
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } while (name.isEmpty()); // will loop until not empty
    }
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at CustomerInfo.main(CustomerInfo.java:19)

line 19 is this:

```
        } while (name.isEmpty()); // will loop until not empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that would check if the number was a `double` (and also will work for `int`), and then in the same call you just check the value entered is not `null`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("2.22");
        test("2");
        test("");
    }

    public static void test(String s) {
        if (checkIfNumber(s) && (s != null || !s.isEmpty())) {
            System.out.println("number is entered");
        } else {
            System.out.println("number was not entered");
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkIfNumber(String s) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            //provide a pop up here if required
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter a valid number or the input was empty");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for double

```
double balance=0;
    do {
        try {
        balance = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter initial balance:", "Enter balance", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, balance);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid entry, \nPlease enter balance in double format");
    }
    } while (balance==0);
```

and this for string

```
String csName = "";
    do {
        try {
            csName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Customer Name:", "Enter Customer Name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            if (csName.equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter customer name");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, csName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "invalid entry, \nplease enter customer name in string format");
        }
    } while (csName.equals(""));
```